# Отчет времени

Tags: android, дата, календарь

Задача такая: есть устройство на котором `android` стоит.

Есть приложение с кнопочкой. По нажатию на кнопочку должна запоминаться дата нажатия и по запросу выдаваться на сервер! НО, кто мешает изменить дату?

Поэтому я подумал и решил, что лучше будет считать количество дней, прошедшее с момента нажатия на эту кнопочку и отсылать на сервер. Вот только как считать эти дни независимо от текущей даты?

Answer (score 1):

Использовать Alarm Service.
http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/alarmservice.php

**Обновление**

На выключенном планшете ничего работать не будет. Тогда остается использовать системную дату и как-то контролировать ее. Например, считывать дату с одного из серверов интернет или получать ее из GPS.

Comment: Даже если планшет был полностью разряжен и выключен на несколько дней?

Comment: Обновил ответ

Comment: А как насчет отслеживать событие изменения времени и корректировать с часами устройства?